# Hovering on dropdown menu brings content under it slightly up and create a margin on right side of page

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

The problem is with the photography website I have created for some reason just on the **"Contact"** and **"Bio"** pages. It is only when the screen is resized so you will need to shrink down till the layout changes. Then when you hover over the menu tab "Albums" and the drop down menu appears  it is pulling the content under it up slightly. It also creates a margin on the right that creates a scroll bar at the bottom. I have been combing through the CSS over and over trying to tweak things, can't find a solution though. 
The website is:

"Bio" http://www.sairjanephotography.co.uk/bio.html

"Contact" http://www.sairjanephotography.co.uk/contact/contact.html

Also I just noticed the actual contact page drop down menu is hard to actually get onto with the mouse where as the Bio one isn't.
Any help appreciated

Comment: What browser/os are you using? I can't replicate the issue on Chrome Win7

Comment: Its windows 7, Firefox 31.0 I am using.

Comment: I just tried it on Chrome and it has the same problem for me. It's when the screen is shrunk down until the menu goes horizontal at the top rather than vertical at the side. Then when you hover over "albums".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ditch the javascript approach, and just use CSS.  [Something like this](http://codepen.io/srsgores/pen/AmlvC) would work; just apply `left: 100%` to get it on the right instead of below.

**Edit**: sorry for not reading the problem earlier.  Your problem is that you have defined `width` on your `ul` element.  On line 277, you have:

```
/*Re-centres the nav menu on phones from tablet*/
 @media screen and (max-width:37em){
  .menu ul{
    font-size:4em;
    width:18em;

  }
}
```

But if you remove `width: 18em`, all is well, it appears.

To clarify on this, you shouldn't be setting fixed widths if you want to acheive a good mobile design.  Instead, try to use tricks like `text-align: center` (coupled with `display: inline-block`, and `display: block; margin: 0 auto;`.

I think the other part of this question had to do with the hiding of the title.  If you still want your header to show, you could either change its `z-index` to anything higher than the dropdown, **or** you could use an ajacent selector to give the main content a `margin-top` when the dropdown is active.

For example:

```
.menu.open + main {
    margin-top 3em;
}

/* Add some transitions for show possibly */
main {
    transition: 1s ease margin
}
```

Comment: The menu is just CSS. The javascript is for the photo albums.

Comment: Thank you, that has solved both problems in one it seems. I am sure there was a reason I had set that width but I can't for the life of me remember why! Thanks again though!